# Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx512M when creating a new key store

Tags: java, android-studio, environment-variables, apk, jks

In android studio I want to create a generated signed APK, I have edited the _JAVA_OPTIONS variable's value in the Environment Variables, but still not luck, this is the error I keep running into:

[image: The error I get when I press OK]

Answer (score 2):

Close android-studio and 
reopen it from terminal like this:

`unset _JAVA_OPTIONS && android-studio`

Answer (score 1):

Yes! I figured it out, The problem was'nt setting the _JAVA_OPTIONS value in the environment variables, I had to delete the variable _JAVA_OPTIONS.